# Mapa de calor de Perú en Google Geocharts

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

Intento crear un Mapa de calor de Perú en Google Geocharts, en la documentación de google hay un ejemplo pero de todo el mundo y necesito uno de un país en especifico: Perú

Ejemplo de Google:

Este mismo ejemple quiero adaptarlo pero a un país en especifico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages':['geochart'],
        // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
        // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
        'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Peru', 200],

        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Referencia**

Encontré en un pagina que es posible realizarlo , pero no especifican como?

http://www.danielpinero.com/como-crear-mapa-calor-peru

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: vas a tener que encontrar alguna fuente donde estén mapeados todos los departamentos del Perú...

Comment: @fredyfx hola, gracias por tu comentario, actualice mi pregunta con los codigos que reconoce los mapas de google , pero aun no logro realizarlo , esto es muy facil hacerlo con data studio de google, pero ahora deseo integrarlo a mi aplicacion, gracias y espero cualquier sugerencia

Comment: Ya lo solucione , gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Coloca la respuesta en la parte inferior de esta página y en 24 horas la marcas como aceptada. Felicitaciones :) y gracias por colaborar con la comunidad

Comment: gracias , acabo de realizarlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ISO 3166-2:PE** (Codigos de Departamentos de Peru que reconocen los mapas de google,segun la ISO 3166-2)

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:PE

```
Por código

PE-AMA  Amazonas
PE-ANC  Ancash
PE-APU  Apurímac
PE-ARE  Arequipa
PE-AYA  Ayacucho
PE-CAJ  Cajamarca
PE-CAL  Callao
PE-CUS  Cusco
PE-HUC  Huánuco
PE-HUV  Huancavelica
PE-ICA  Ica
PE-JUN  Junín
PE-LAL  La Libertad
PE-LAM  Lambayeque
PE-LIM  Lima (departamento)
PE-LMA  Lima (provincia de la capital)
PE-LOR  Loreto
PE-MDD  Madre de Dios
PE-MOQ  Moquegua
PE-PAS  Pasco
PE-PIU  Piura
PE-PUN  Puno
PE-SAM  San Martín
PE-TAC  Tacna
PE-TUM  Tumbes
PE-UCA  Ucayali
```

**SOLUCION**

```
data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['PE-AMA', 466],

        ]);

        var options = {
        region: 'PE', // Peru
        resolution:'provinces'//muestre las provincias/departamentos
        };
```

**REFERENCIAS**

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#important